# automated semi-circular path movement with pygame

Tags: python, path, pygame, game-physics

I'm trying to create a traffic simulator using python (+ pygame and math libs).

I'm stuck at car movements, I've managed to create a fixed horizontal and vertical path using a list of coordinates, using nested for loops.

Now, since I'm in a crossroads I now have to make the 1/4 of a circle to make a left or right turn.

The car has to make a straight path for n pixels (and it's ok) then have to make the 1/4 following a circular path and then proceed towards a straight line again.

I have a list of coordinates, however, I don't know how to make it turn around the center of the circumference (which I know the coordinates of) while also turning the image relative to the center!

I'll give you an idea of the problem using an **image**
[image]
The red paths "1" are done, the problem is the blue tract "2", "O" coordinates are known, there are 4 "O" in total (one for each path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the equation of a circle which is `(x – h)^2 + (y – k)^2 = r^2` where (h,k) are the coordinates of the cercle's center and r the radius.
The idea in your case could be to draw all discrete points (x,y) that verify this equation,
here is an example (for points where x and y are positive regarding the origin, if we follow your example):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
center = (10,10)
radius = 5
th = 0.01
for x in np.arange(center[0],center[0]+radius+th, th):
    for y in np.arange(center[1], center[1]+radius+th, th):
        if abs((x-center[0])**2 +  (y-center[1])**2 - radius**2) < th:
            plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

You can then control the number of points with the th, and even draw lines instead of just points to speed up the process